# When I use Androidplot in my Fragment it can not read values from line_point_formatter_with_labels.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, androidplot

I am trying to use the example from [this link](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/9088a7b1ae536fceb9b570ec07c2eb39fa0a13a0/docs/quickstart.md?fileviewer=file-view-default)

[image]

I did small amendment to the code and I am using a fragment instead of activity like in the example code. Now, I am having issues with the  `line_point_formatter_with_labels.xml` and `line_point_formatter_with_labels_2.xml` config files. The example code can not read values from the files. It happens at the line:

```
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format =
                    new LineAndPointFormatter(getActivity(), R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_labels);
```

I have errors like that

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "#00AA00".

Any idea why it is happening ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue that manifests very similarly to this that appears to be caused some sort of undocumented change to the Android Gradle plugin in 3.0.1.

If you want to check to see if this is what's impacting you, the short term fix is to revert to 2.3.3.  The issue will also be resolved in Androidplot 1.5.2.

BTW, Androidplot has moved it's primary repo home from Bitbucket to [Github](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot).  You can use either one, but the Bitbucket repo occasionally lags behind by a release.